# Can I automatically run commands after Linux Mint Installation?

Tags: bash, installation, linux-mint, livecd

That's what I want: I want to run a bash file (composed mostly by `apt-get`'s and instructions to download and install `.deb` files) just after, or during, Linux Mint installation. I've found many tutorials about how to edit a Linux Mint ISO, but they don't show how can I add commands.

Furthermore, other tutorials show how to edit the Linux Mint Live CD. That would automatically change the system that will be installed in the computer by that CD?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you saved the commands to an executable shell script (ex. Bash) file, you could just run it after installing Mint. Not fully automatic, but it's the easiest I can think of.

If you stored the script on another partition/drive/USB, or if your live DVD (Mint's ISO is too big to fit on a CD) is on a USB with a writeable filesystem you could add the files right to a folder on the same partition of the USB.

And if you downloaded the `.deb` files once, you could install them all at once to any new system with a `dpkg -iR <folder-of-debs>`, no need to update the package index files & re-download the .deb's for every computer.

---

Or, if a script isn't exactly desired, then you probably want to look into customizing the installation program (`ubiquity`, according to it's man page is a front end for debian-installer). Read & master these files for enlightenment:

- ## [Automating Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation)

  With respect to automation, [ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity), the desktop CD installer, works much in the same way that debian-installer, the alternate CD installer does. Therefore, it is recommended that you first read the [debian-installer installation guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/) and create a working preseed file for that before continuing here.

  Specifically:

  - [B.5. Advanced options

    B.5.1. Running custom commands during the installation

    B.5.2. Using preseeding to change default values](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs05.html.en)
  - [DebianInstaller](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller) - Automate installs with [preseed](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed)
  - [DebianInstaller FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/FAQ)
    Q: How to use preseeding? How to use network console with preseeding?
    A: see [DebianInstaller/Preseed](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed) [link above] and [DebianInstaller/NetworkConsole](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/NetworkConsole)

Comment: I already run it after installing Mint, but I want make the process totally automatic. About the deb files: they are re-downloaded everytime because the script was make to be adaptable, always finding the most recent version download link using web crawler (needed to install Lazarus for example).

Comment: @GammaStudio updated answer with ubiquity customizing info